# React , "product/:id" page causes components assets to load from incorrect path(wrong path)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router, react-router-dom

im creating a Product linding page (single product page) with react but when loading the navbar component

it couses the componint's assists to load from wrong path for examble product page path is (/product/:id)
the navbar component will go (/product/:id/assist name ) to get the assist witch will not load the assist
because that is not the right path for the asities.
the exists on the (./assist name )

app.js file

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Container>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/"  element={<Home />} />     
          <Route path="/products/:id" element= {<SingleProductPage/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Container>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

single product page
that has's the (/product/:id) path

```
function SingleProductPage() {

 
  
  return (
    

    <div id="single-Container">
      
      <Navbar/>
     
      single page

    </div>
    



    )
}
```

the navbar component

```
 <div id="Navbar-SearchIcon" >
    <img src="../searchIcon.png" alt="" />


<div id="Navbar-BasketButton" >
       <img src="./basket-icon.png" alt="" />
          </div>
```

[when im on (/) path or any other path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkLNz.png)

[when im on (/product/:id) path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2drf.png)

[how the navbar should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPsT5.png)

[how the navbar look like on product/:id page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDFnB.png)

Comment: Basically it seems like you should be using absolute paths to assets instead of relative paths. We can't see where any assets are referenced though in the incomplete code snippets. Can you [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve]?

Comment: like this >>???

Comment: Yes. And sorry, can you also share the PUBLIC directory structure, i.e. where the images are located there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image sources are using relative paths instead of absolute paths in the PUBLIC directory. When you navigate into a sub-route the path to assets will be different when using relative paths, they will be relative from the current URL pathname.

Absolute paths will start with `"/"` which is the public directory. Here's an Example:

```
<div id="Navbar-SearchIcon" >
  <img src="/images/searchIcon.png" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="Navbar-BasketButton" >
  <img src="/images/basket-icon.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

```
/public
  -/images
    -searchIcon.png
    -basket-icon.png
    ....
  ....
/src
  ....
```